# While uploading a file, getting "Could not delete file C:\Users\..." error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am using spring boot and mysql for my application. While I am trying to upload a file it shows error message like given below,

```html
java.io.IOException: UT010015: Could not delete file C:\Users\KARTHI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\undertow7745669140970195692upload
 at io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl.delete(PartImpl.java:111)
 at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.cleanupMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:86)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.cleanupMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1104)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:989)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
 at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
```

and my coding is,

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8080/surf/upload">
File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> Name: <input
   type="text" name="name"><br /> <br /> <input type="submit"
   value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

and my java class

```html
 @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
         @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
         if (!file.isEmpty()) {
             try {
                 byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                 BufferedOutputStream stream =
                         new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/Test/surfImg/")));
                 stream.write(bytes);
                 stream.close();
                 return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
             }
         } else {
             return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
         }
     }
```

Comment: Do you have the administration permission? Maybe is just that. Because it is in a user folder

Comment: @Tupac yes, i am checking with admin only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bug in Undertow ([UNDERTOW-542](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-542)) discussed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3966) in Spring Boot context. To quote the [analysis of Andy Wilkinson](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3966#issuecomment-140742820):

> The good news is that the exception's benign and you can safely ignore it. All it's telling you, albeit very noisily, is that the file couldn't be deleted as it's already been deleted. The reason is that there's a race condition in Undertow that means that two threads end up trying to delete the file at the same time.
>
> *[...]*
>
> This has been fixed in Undertow 1.3 and 1.2. Spring Boot 1.3 uses Undertow 1.3 so we're good there. Unfortunately Spring Boot 1.2 uses Undertow 1.1 so we'll just have to live with the benign warning there.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is with some of the version of Spring Boot. As for example, getting error when using Spring Boot 2.7.8 version. But error go away when started using older 2.1.7.RELEASE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).